# The following error occurred attempting to run the project model server process (1.0.0-rc4-004771)

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2017

Compilation error in Visual Studio 2015 when a new .NET Core 1 web app is created, if you have already installed Visual Studio 2017 RC.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a link that fixes this issue very clearly and here is the link.
https://chamindac.blogspot.com/2017/02/resolve-msb4019-imported-project.html

Comment: Fixed it for me.

Comment: It is generally not a good answer to just post a link as they can go down. Please insert the essence of the solution that is detailed enough to stand as an answer on its own, with the link as a reference.

Answer (score 13):

I had this problem too, it seems that for some reason the latest .NET Core tools (that is installed via Visual Studio 2017) isn't compatible with Visual Studio 2015 and since it can't load the tools you get this message.

You can fix this in the global.json in your solution folder. Look for the `"sdk"` section and adjust the `"version"` to what you have installed on your computer. If you have done a default installation it would reside under %ProgramFiles%\dotnet\sdk.

For example I have a version called `1.0.0-preview.2-1-003180`, so my global.json looks like this:

```
{
  "projects": [ "src" ],
  "sdk": { "version": "1.0.0-preview2-1-003180" }
}
```

Comment: Note, in solutions with more than one project, I found that I had to put that b`global.json` file in the root of each project folder.

Comment: @ChadRichardson That shouldn't be neccessary, I think you'll have some other issue then. Difficult to say exactly what.

Comment: I've no global.json in the entire solution folder.

Comment: @MikedeKlerk Not sure what the issue you have is, but the global.json file is not a required file. The newest SDK is used if you don't have a global.json file with a sdk definition in the folder (or it's parents where you run the client tools from) as described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-json.